# How to combine monthly price return for different year into one dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have get dataframe of monthly return from year 2013 to year 2019, i want to combine the monthly return into one dataframe with columns names from 2013 to 2019 and index from January to December. Therefore i get a dataframe of monthly return for year 2014 to 2019.

How can i do it ?  Thank

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as ply
import quandl

start=pd.to_datetime('2012.01.01')
end=pd.datetime.now()       #pd.to_datetime('2019.07.20')

btc= quandl.get("BITFINEX/BTCUSD.4",start_date=start,end_date=end, authtoken="F51kbhqij4J1o73V5vXT")

btc["pct"]=btc["Last"]/btc["Last"].shift(1)-1

btc=btc.resample(rule='M').apply(lambda x: x[-1])

btc["month_pct"]=btc["Last"]/btc["Last"].shift(1)-1

btc["year"]=btc.index.year
btc["month"]=btc.index.month_name()

btc_month=btc

btc_2014=btc_month.loc[btc_month["year"]==2014]
btc_2015=btc_month.loc[btc_month["year"]==2015]
btc_2016=btc_month.loc[btc_month["year"]==2016]
btc_2017=btc_month.loc[btc_month["year"]==2017]
btc_2018=btc_month.loc[btc_month["year"]==2018]
btc_2019=btc_month.loc[btc_month["year"]==2019]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gyeck.png)

btc_2019 output is like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gyeck.png)

Comment: Can you post a few rows of your dataframe so that we can work on that example

Comment: Thanks but i wanted the data no the code. Instead of that image if you could post a few rows of the data frame, it would be easy for us to copy that and work on that data

Comment: i have updated but you may have to install quandl firstly to get access to the data